# Java process hangs after exiting Eclipse

Tags: java, process, eclipse

On my machine whenever I work with Eclipse (on Suns JDK), the **java process does not terminate** after I exit Eclipse. Therefore after working on several projects over the day, I sometimes need to kill all those Java processes manually to free my RAM again.

This bugs me for about 2 years now, while all these parts have gone through different versions:

- Ubuntu
- Eclipse (and all the installed plugins)
- Suns JDK

I've even tried to attach a VM debugger to the Java processes to see what's going on, but had no success.

Although it would be nice to find the reason for the problem, I'm meanwhile more interested in a workaround to automatically kill those processes once a day. I imagine a script to kill the Java processes, but to make some exceptions depending on the command line parameters of the Java process (e.g. I have Subsonic and the Playstation Media Server running all the time).

What are your ideas to automatically (and selectively) kill the Java processes?

Answer (score 1):

You describe an old bug in some installations of Eclipse. For example, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=184575
I cannot remember what was the cause of this issue, however a clean installation helped fix the problem.

Specifically,

1. Do not use the packaged Eclipse that is found in the Ubuntu repositories. The packaging of Eclipse is a difficult process and the package from the repositories is not the best way to install Eclipse.
2. Install Eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org. It is quite straightforward to install.
   I recommend to install in /opt
   You can create first a /opt/eclipse directory and change the owner to your user account, therefore, you can install updates, etc easily.
3. You may have to start from scratch with a new ~/.eclipse/ so that old customisation is cleared, and you start with a new environment.